# Firefox extension trying to insert chrome:// image into page

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox extension and I am trying to make it add an image stored with the extension (the kind that you access using chrome://, although I'm not sure if there is an official name)

```
body.innerHTML+="<div style=\"position:fixed;top:0em;left:0em;background-color:white;\"><img src=\"chrome://tumblrscrollr/content/save.png\" /></div>";
```

This should put save.png at the top left of the page, however nothing appears there (not even the white background).  If I replace chrome://tumblrscrollr/content/save.png with a url on the internet, the image displays properly.  If I visit chrome://tumblrscrollr/content/save.png directly in the address bar, it displays fine.  I assume there's some security thing or something going on that doesn't allow an img tag in a page to access an extension's files, but since google doesn't support symbols and any search for 'chrome' just returns the browser, I am finding it very hard to find any answer.

Comment: added the more general 'firefox-addon' tag - it is unclear to me that this post should be tagged 'firefox-addon-sdk' tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`contentaccessible` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible) for the `tumblrscrollr` chrome package, this will allow web pages to use its images. Meaning that your `chrome.manifest` file should have a line like this:

```
content tumblrscrollr foo/bar contentaccessible=yes
```

Note that this flag always has to be specified on the `content` entry but it affects any address starting with `chrome://tumblrscrollr/` meaning also `chrome://tumblrscrollr/skin/` for example.

Btw, you shouldn't add elements like that - this makes the browser to parse the entire document body again which is slow and might cause all kinds of side-effects. If you need to add a single element then just create that element and add it, e.g.:

```js
var element = body.ownerDocument.createElement("div");
element.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;top:0em;left:0em;background-color:white;");
element.innerHTML = "<img src=\"chrome://tumblrscrollr/content/save.png\" />";
body.appendChild(element);
```